# The tingly electric shocks

Tags: single-word-requests

Okay so you guys hopefully would be aware of the tingles that pass inside your body which are like light electric shocks. Could anybody tell me a word which would describe it? Specially when someone you love is the cause of those.

Comment: "on-pins-and-needles" might be the phrase you seek

Comment: What's wrong with "tingle"?

Comment: @Hot Licks "Tingle[s]" doesn't really convey the same order of magnitude as the OP's "electric shocks".

Comment: @NMI - I've often heard "tingle" used in this sense, or used it myself.

Comment: **Which** tingles? There are many different kinds of tingles that can go through your body feeling like tiny electric shocks. Some are pleasant (tingling), others are unpleasant. People you love can be the cause of many of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to go with a pretty snooty sort of borrowed-French word, you might try *frisson*.  There is quibbling over some details in the [Wikipedia article for that word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisson), but the meaning of the word does not seem to be in dispute. Here's [its Merriam-Webster online entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frisson).

Comment: I like it, @Blaise. If one is speaking of or writing about matters of the heart, I should think "a pretty snooty sort of borrowed-French word" is entirely appropriate, if not de rigueur. <3

Comment: Frission might be the appropriate word

Answer (score 0):

[**Quiver**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quiver) could possibly be one of your options too.

From ODE:

> A slight trembling movement or sound, especially one caused by a sudden strong emotion.

Usage example, again from ODE:

> She couldn't help the *quiver* in her voice.